# Building A 32-bit x86 Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I am using buildroot for developing a my own customized Linux system. I am trying to Build a Kernel for x86. When I try to  cross compile kernel using

```
make CROSS_COMPILE = i686 - linux - ARCH = i386
make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least to remove the spaces

```
 make CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux ARCH=i386
```

but I am not sure that is enough. Read [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: Thanks I have tried that before but I was getting different error at that time
    make: i686-linuxgcc: Command not found
    CHK     include/linux/version.h
    CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
    CC      kernel/bounds.s
    /bin/sh: i686-linuxgcc: not found
    make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
    make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
Any idea about this..

Comment: You need to read a lot more documentations. Take several hours to read them. Don't try commands without understanding them.